# How can I link two different projects written in two different languages like C++ and C# in VS?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-studio-2008

How can I link two different projects written in two different languages like C++ and C# in VS ?
for example, I have a program written in c++ sum two numbers,and another program written in C# multiply two numbers,i want to link them together in VS.
many thanks and best regard

Comment: What do you mean with 'link'?

Comment: No, managed code doesn't use a linker.  Working with modules is a rabbit hole.  You can accomplish something similar by switching from C# to C++/CLI.  Very different language though.  Putting output from different projects into one file is otherwise simple, everybody calls it setup.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with creating DLL file in one language and using it in another can doing this victim.

Answer (score 0):

You have two basic options:

- [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - Works only from C# to C/C++, not the other way. Can only be used for C APIs (you can't pass C++ objects via PInvoke).
- [C++/CLI wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx) - C++/CLI is a managed version of C++ which can combine managed and native code. Using that, you can wrap C++ classes/APIs in C++/CLI APIs (which can  be then used from C#). IT also works the other way. However this involves writing more code than PInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

linking the way you describe it does not make much sense or is at minimum open to interpretation.

In Visual Studio surely you can have a single solution containing a C++ project, a C# project and a VB.NET project, let's say those are all class libraries. You build the whole solution and you get everything compiled and built into 3 separated DLLs.

Then in case you add a Console app or a windows forms application to the solution, if such project is in C# or VB.NET you can simply add the reference to the other projects except for the C++ if it's not a managed CLI/C++.

to use the functions of the C++ project from C#/VB.NET you would probably need to use DLLImport.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example the simplest option may be to have one program run the other program and read in it's output.

But I suspect that's not the answer you're looking for.  For native C++ and C#, you have three other obvious options:

1. Using [.NET COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to write/produce a COM object that can be used from the other language.
2. Writing some C++\CLI code to interface between the C++ code and the C# code.  If you have no need for pure native C++ code, then it'd be possible to write your entire C++ section using C++\CLI
3. Using PInvoke to call from C# into a C++ DLL.

Answer (score 0):

you can not link two executable. what u can do is to define one of them as DLL and link it to the other. Try to define 2 projects, csporj for the C#, vcproj for the C++ and another main (could be either). Then create dependencies between the main and the two project.
Do you also want to call the one from the other ?

Comment: no , just i want to create an .exe that contain this 2 programs and print the results!